# Maven: What is the <url> element in the <scm> config used for?

Tags: maven-3, maven-scm

When configuring the `<scm>` element in a pom.xml, what is the `<url>` tag used for?

Example from http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/usage.html:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://somerepository.com/svn_repo/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://somerepository.com/svn_repo/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>http://somerepository.com/view.cvs</url>
</scm>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had set up [viewCV](http://www.viewvc.org/) or some other tool which gives you access to your code via a web web browser then you'd put the URL in here.

Comment: Thanks! Would be nice if the plugin page documented that.